# iOS7 background fetch?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager, ios7.1

In my app I want to send some data to server using iOS 7 Background fetch feature.I also selected  Background fetch check box in capabilities section of target(and of course a flag added in plist automatically).

In AppDelegate I did this :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [application setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum];
    //[application setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:10]; also tried this
    return YES;
}
```

and then in delegate method I did this:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler{

        LocationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

        LocationManager.delegate = self;
        LocationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        LocationManager.distanceFilter = 50.0;
        [LocationManager startUpdatingLocation];

        /** NEW DATA EXISTS AND WAS SUCCESSFULLY PROCESSED **/
        if (YES) {

             completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
        }
        else
             completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultFailed);
 }
```

Then I connected my iPhone to XCode and ran the app and click Simulate Background fetch from debug menu. The delegate method was called and location was updated on server once but it never happened again, the system never wakes the app up in the background.
What i'm doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit:** Is it possible to send data on server using background fetch?
**Edit-2** If i use remote notification instead Background fetch to send data on server then in that case Is it guaranteed that system will wake my app up once it got remote notification?

Comment: Before take any decision go through comments under @walle84 answer.

Comment: Just a heads up, `Simulate Background Fetch` is broken in Xcode 6 (verified not working in 6.3.1) and is mentioned in the 'Known Issues' section of the Xcode 6 release notes. [Other thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29974714/939757) [Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/xc6_release_notes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH4-DontLinkElementID_32)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer is that the call to **performFetchWithCompletionHandler** method depends on iOS of device as to when call it. I also had the same issue long back and found out that it could be called in few min or hours or day or week too. Also ** UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum** doesn't mean that it will call it in minimum time ,its just could be never or minimum which would at end depend on OS to make call for preformFetch method. So at end you could wait for OS to make call for performFetchWithCompletionHandler method.

Comment: But i want to update location every 20 or 30 minute and as mentioned i also tried to set my own time interval like 10 seconds.

Comment: @Bharat You will need to use Location Service Background Mode on your app. Then from there you can run an NSTimer with your said interval and startUpdating Location. performFetchWithCompletionHandler will not be performed on the set interval because the OS decides whenever to call it.

Comment: Even if you set time interval of 20 or 10 second it won't work as I read about background fetch. It totally depends on OS to make call for that performFetch method as told earlier it could be hours or days. I did tried myself and faced same issue when was creating a demo of it.

Comment: @jeraldo i did same before trying background fetch, but keep an app always alive in background is not a good idea and apple will never approve it.

Comment: @Bharat here is a [link](http://gooddevbaddev.wordpress.com/2013/10/22/ios-7-running-location-based-apps-in-the-background/) this might be helpful for u.

Comment: @Bharat I think you may use performFetchWithCompletionHandler by using a notification that is sent to your app every n seconds/minutes. Upon receiving the notification, you might try to update the location.

Comment: @jeraldo don't know about approval stuff but app feature's and what it will provide would for it I guess. Also if your keeping your app way to active in background then it might be problem for you to be approved.

Comment: No point of using performFetchWithCompletionHandler method when there is Location Service Background Mode stuff. @jeraldo what's your point there?

Comment: @walle84 I am also not sure about this. I am actually working on a similar project as Bharat. But if the background location service is set for that app then it may be approved, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @Bharat see this link if this helps you http://gooddevbaddev.wordpress.com/2013/10/22/ios-7-running-location-based-apps-in-the-background/

Comment: @jeraldo I just had a small talk with my colleague and he said that Location Service Background Mode will work fine and according to him it will keep app active in background for more than 10 min as he had created a demo using it. Rest depends on bharat to start off with it and se what it lead's too. Also for performFetch method I'm pretty sure it's OS that will rule it and not we (coder's) and also calling it from notification is not a way as apple provided that location in background stuff.

Comment: @walle84 sorry about the link. it means i got it from you so thanks. I have also tried the location service at background mode for a few hours, but for extensive time like 3 hrs and so on... it gets killed. do you have a suggestion for me and Bharat?

Comment: Edit-1 Yes you could send data using backgroundFetch and it's totally upto you what you want to do in performFetch method.
Edit-2 Again yes , you make you app active with notification fire.

Comment: @jeraldo i had faced the same issue. as my app only able to send data on server for a few hours(2 or 3 hours) and then was killed.

Comment: Best option is to fire push notification to make your app active and fetch data. As far I know keeping app active for that long is not good from apple point of view. So you need to go through your flow of your app and make of ways for doing stuff. Also I don't have much idea about your app flow so cann't make suggestion or comment on it.

Comment: See you could fire a push notification and let user decide if he wants to update his app data or not. If yes then you could fire background location fetch service and update your data. Also provide a refresh button in your app in case if usr has not updated its data and open's app ,at same time want's to have latest data

Comment: @walle84 it is must for me to send user location to server every 20-30 minutes if app is in background, so if i send push from server after every n minute and on receiving the push it must send location, i read about remote notification and what i understand from that it work like silent notification and user will not know about it.if it is true then it must be fine for me.

Comment: You could provide a ring sound when notification is received and let user decide if he want's to update his location or not.

Comment: Please check [this link](http://www.g8production.com/post/72656082173/ios7-multitasking-silent-notifications) it says- A silent notification, if not used in conjunction with a push notification, is not visible to the user. and i'm fine with this no need to user approval ie. i got notification and i update location on server thats it.

Comment: So is using a silent notification more reliable and less battery consuming than updating the location using an nstimer?

Comment: Yes using notification is good way instead of keeping your app running and consuming battery. As in iOS 8 apple given user to check for which app is doing what. So user will not support such app which keep on running in background and using battery like a candy.

Answer (score 0):

The iOS is intelligent in the way that if the background operation from your app consumes more resources, it will even stop calling it again. The time interval for background fetch is never fixed and OS calls it whenever it is free. If your app's background operation consumes less resource, it is more likely that it will be called again. You can't necessarily update location every 20 or 30 minutes. Even if you mention the interval, if the OS is not free, it won't execute your fetch operation.